# Xamarin ProgressBar binding

Tags: xaml, xamarin, mvvm, progress-bar

I have a page that have a cardview in it .

C# Code for BadgeView.cs (BadgeView XAML has stacklayout named card):

```
 public BadgeView(BadgesGroup badgesGroup)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BadgeLogo.Source = badgesGroup.Logo;
            var cardsview = new CardsView
            {
                IsClippedToBounds = true,
                IsCyclical = true,
                MoveWidthPercentage = 0.3,
                WidthRequest = 250,
                HeightRequest=250,
                ItemsSource = badgesGroup.Badges,
                ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => new BadgePopUp())
            };
            cardsview.Children.Add(new IndicatorsControl());
            cardsview.Children.Add(new RightArrowControl());
            cardsview.Children.Add(new LeftArrowControl());
            card.Children.Add(cardsview);
        }
```

the card view item source is set to a list of badge objects with this model :

```
public class badge {
string Name {get;set;}
string Description {get;set;}
int CurrentProgress {get;set;}
int GoalProgress {get;set;}
}
```

the itemtemplate BadgePopUp is :

```
<StackLayout 
    Orientation="Vertical"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    VerticalOptions="Start"
    Padding="5"
    BackgroundColor="Goldenrod">
    <StackLayout.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:ProgressConverter x:Key="xprogress" xCurrentProgress="{Binding CurrentProgress}"
                                     xGoalProgress="{Binding  GoalProgress}"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </StackLayout.Resources>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label Text="{Binding Title}"></Label>
        <Label Text="{Binding Description}"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
        <ProgressBar x:Name="Progressbar" ProgressColor="Purple" 
            Progress="{Binding Converter={StaticResource xprogress}}">
        </ProgressBar>
        <Label Text="{Binding Description}"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

inside the cardview there is two labels binded with Name and description .
also there is a progressBar.

what I want to do is to take currentProgress and divide it by GoalProgress and set the results into progressbar.progress .

I tried using a converter but it wont work for me .
here is the code for the converter

```
public class ProgressConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public int xCurrentProgress { get; set; }
        public int xGoalProgress { get;set; }
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {

            return (float) xCurrentProgress / xGoalProgress;
        }
```

This would work for me :

```
 <local:ProgressConverter x:Key="xprogress" xCurrentProgress="2"
                                         xGoalProgress="3"/>
```

But this would not work

```
 <local:ProgressConverter x:Key="xprogress" xCurrentProgress="{Binding CurrentProgress}"
                                         xGoalProgress="{Binding  GoalProgress}"/>
```

with the following error :

```
No property, bindable property, or event found for 'xCurrentProgress', or mismatching type between value and property.
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: Provide the full code or sample so that people can help you better .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Thanks , Just edited and added sample code .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you misunderstand the using of `IValueConverter` and **ViewModel** . If want to binding data , you need to create ViewModel to bind it. And if want to convert value , first need to bind a data soure ,then bind a value converter to convert the paramater of data source .Having a look at this [Xamarin.Forms Binding Value Converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters) document.

> Data bindings usually transfer data from a source property to a target property, and in some cases from the target property to the source property.

From code you just bind a `IValueConverter` , this will not work.

Here is a **Sample** about using **ViewModel** :

```
public class ProgresssModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int currentprogressvalue;

    public int CurrentProgressValue
    {
        set
        {
            if (currentprogressvalue != value)
            {
                currentprogressvalue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ProgressValue");
                progressvalue = (double)currentprogressvalue / totalprogressvalue;
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return currentprogressvalue;
        }
    }

    private int totalprogressvalue;

    public int TotalProgressValue
    {
        set
        {
            if (totalprogressvalue != value)
            {
                totalprogressvalue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ProgressValue");
                progressvalue = (double)currentprogressvalue / totalprogressvalue;
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return totalprogressvalue;
        }
    }

    private double progressvalue;

    public double ProgressValue
    {
        set
        {
            if (progressvalue != value)
            {
                progressvalue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ProgressValue");
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return progressvalue;
        }
    }

    public ProgresssModel()
    {
        currentprogressvalue = 30;
        totalprogressvalue = 100;
        progressvalue = (double)currentprogressvalue / totalprogressvalue;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

In **XAML** , adding a non-customed `ProgressBar` ,and adding `Button` to show data changed 
when runtime for example :

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke" Padding="20">
    <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    <ProgressBar x:Name="myprogress" Progress="{Binding ProgressValue}"/>
    <Button Text="change" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Now can bind it to `ProgressBar` in **ContentPage** :

```
public partial class SecondPage : ContentPage
{

    ProgresssModel progresssModel;
    public SecondPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        progresssModel = new ProgresssModel();
        myprogress.BindingContext = progresssModel;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progresssModel.CurrentProgressValue = 40;
        progresssModel.TotalProgressValue = 100;
    }
}
```

**Effect** :

[image]

Comment: ll give it a try .. But in the ProgressModel and the button both value set to 30 , 40 and 100 ... how can I have their values taken from their parent element(cardView) ItemSource

Comment: @user2596181 You can set the `ProgressModel` be a static instance .Updated by other element like in cardView's ItemSource.

Comment: I know how to access the itemSource data from xaml like this : <Label Text="{Binding Description}"></Label>  Description is a string in badge object . 
But I dont know how to access it from code in C# can you give an example ?

Comment: @user2596181 Okey ,eg: `label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new ProgresssModel().TextValue);`

Comment: this example set a binding to the label . what I meant is I already have a cardView with itemsource and itemTemplate , the itemtemplate has the progressbar , the progress bar takes two values from the cardview itemsource and divide them together . I can set one value to progress bar like this : <ProgressBar Progress="{Binding CurrentProgress"> but I can not figure out how to divide CurrentProgress and GoalProgress and set progress bar progress to the result .
I hope I made it more clear .

Comment: in other words , from your givin example how do I assign progresssModel.CurrentProgressValue to values from parent source item in C# code .

Comment: @user2596181 Got it . First you can modify the struct of `ProgresssModel` to fit the `itemsource` of cardView .Then you can set ItemSource to ProgresssModel as follow: `ObservableCollection<Employee> employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();employees = cardView.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<Employee>;` . In addition, I want to know how you set data to `itemsource` of cardView .If using model , I think this model can also be a `progresssModel` , then it can directly used in `ProgressBar`.

Comment: I updated my Converter and the error is gone but the value is passed as 0 . can you take a look at this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57988568/ivalue-converter-property-in-xamarin?noredirect=1#comment102385410_57988568

Comment: @user2596181 Okey , if this answer be helpful , thanks for marking in advance .I will have a check with new question. If idea will share with you.