# Ivalue Converter Property in Xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following converter that takes two properties :

```
public class ProgressConverter : BindableObject, IMarkupExtension, IValueConverter 
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty CurrentProgressProperty = BindableProperty.Create("CurrentProgress", typeof(int), typeof(ProgressConverter));
        public static readonly BindableProperty GoalProgressProperty = BindableProperty.Create("GoalProgress", typeof(int), typeof(ProgressConverter));
        public int CurrentProgress
        {
            get { return(int) GetValue(CurrentProgressProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CurrentProgressProperty, value);}
        } 
        public int GoalProgress
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(GoalProgressProperty); }
            set { SetValue(GoalProgressProperty, value);}
        }
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            double progress = (double)CurrentProgress / (double)GoalProgress;
            return progress;
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            return this;
        }
        object IMarkupExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
        }
    }
```

and I am using it inside progressbar to set progress like this  (this works fine no problem , will take 2 and divide it by 5 then put the results into progressbar progress ):

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="Progressbar" ProgressColor="Purple" 
             Progress="{Binding Converter={local:ProgressConverter CurrentProgress=1,GoalProgress=5}}">
</ProgressBar>
```

**But when I do this , it wont work (Point#1)**  : (the value for both CurrentProgress and GoalProgress inside the converter are 0).

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="Progressbar" ProgressColor="Purple" 
             Progress="{Binding Converter={local:ProgressConverter CurrentProgress={Binding xCurrentProgress},GoalProgress={Binding xGoalProgress}}}">
</ProgressBar>
```

Both xCurrentProgress and xGoalProgress are set in the parent itemSource .

Model :

```
public class badge {
string Name {get;set;}
string Description {get;set;}
int xCurrentProgress {get;set;}
int xGoalProgress {get;set;}
}
```

Itemsource setting :

```
public BadgeView(BadgesGroup badgesGroup)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BadgeLogo.Source = badgesGroup.Logo;
            var cardsview = new CardsView
            {
                IsClippedToBounds = true,
                IsCyclical = true,
                MoveWidthPercentage = 0.3,
                WidthRequest = 250,
                HeightRequest=250,
                ItemsSource = badgesGroup.Badges,
                ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => new BadgePopUp())
            };
            cardsview.Children.Add(new IndicatorsControl());
            cardsview.Children.Add(new RightArrowControl());
            cardsview.Children.Add(new LeftArrowControl());
            card.Children.Add(cardsview);
        }
```

How do I make it work for point#1

How can I make the converter takes values from binding like this :

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="Progressbar" ProgressColor="Purple" 
                 Progress="{Binding Converter={local:ProgressConverter CurrentProgress={Binding xCurrentProgress},GoalProgress={Binding xGoalProgress}}}">
    </ProgressBar>
```

Because using above code would result both values of CurrentProgress and GoalProgress  pass 0 not the actual value stored in them .

Comment: Your question is vague please be specific about what are you trying to achieve

Comment: @FreakyAli updated question to be more clear , thanks.

Comment: I do not see any changes as of now!

Comment: I want my converter to take binding values like this : 
<ProgressBar x:Name="Progressbar" ProgressColor="Purple" 
                 Progress="{Binding Converter={local:ProgressConverter CurrentProgress={Binding xCurrentProgress},GoalProgress={Binding xGoalProgress}}}">
    </ProgressBar> ..
this  code would result both values of CurrentProgress and GoalProgress pass 0 not the actual value stored in them .

Comment: @user2596181 Hi , I need to know the code of ItemSource in CardView , you can share it . I will check the mdoel of ItemSource .Maybe not needs to use Converter here.

Comment: I found a solution by using Multibinding , an example is here : https://intellitect.com/multibinding-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: @user2596181 Great , when have time you can share it in answer *.^